# nuxt3 destructuring useLazyAsyncData

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to destructure a response from API as this example:

```
const {
  data: {
    value: [firstResult, secondResult],
  },
  pending,
} = await useLazyAsyncData("explore-brands", () =>
  Promise.all([
    find("brands"),
    find("discover-brand"),
  ])
);
```

but that throws an error:

`TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

How to fix that ?

Comment: Take it step by step. What do you have in `data`? What about `value`? What do you see in your network tab?

Comment: Not sure where `value` is coming from, your `data` should contain the array `Promise.all` returns, so perhaps try: `data: [firstResult, secondResult]`

Comment: Maybe he confused how to access a ref in Vue3, with `.value`.

Comment: yes, I'm considering the .value from ref

Answer (score 1):

useAsyncData/useLazyAsyncData adds  `| null` to the type of `data` (starting with nuxt version `3.0.0-rc.9`).

So you should do something like this:

```js
const { data, pending } = await useLazyAsyncData(...)

if (data.value) {
  const [firstResult, secondResult] = data.value
  // ...
} else {
  // Handle the null case
}
```

PS: Why do you await when you are using the lazy variant?

Comment: sure, the await in this case does not make any sense